# Use Sync Framework without Installation

Tags: c#, visual-studio, microsoft-sync-framework

I developed an application, which uses the Microsoft Sync SDK for syncing Directories. But I want to run the application without installing the sync framework on every computer before. So is there a way to publish the application, including the framework in his program directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just copy the files as Sync Fx still uses COM. If you dont want to manually install the Sync Fx separately, you can bootstrap it with your application installer.